# Parsing 'Complex' JSON with Pig

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

Say I have some moderately complex JSON like

```
{
    "revenue": 100,
    "products":[
            {"name": "Apple", "price": 50},
            {"name": "Banana", "price": 50}
    ]
}
```

Obviously this this a bit contrived, but what's the best way to map this to pig using JsonLoader.

I've tried

```
a = LOAD 'test.json' USING
    JsonLoader('revenue:int,products:[(name:chararray,price:int)]');
```

or

```
a = LOAD 'test.json' USING
    JsonLoader('revenue:int,products:[{(name:chararray,price:int)]}');
```

However, when I `DUMP A`, I get `(100,)` for both.

I've also tried

```
a = LOAD '/json/complex.json'
    USING JsonLoader('revenue:int,products:[{name:chararray,price:int}]');
```

which errors out with `ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 28>  mismatched input 'chararray' expecting LEFT_PAREN`.

What's the best way to parse this for future use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For posterity,

```
a = LOAD 'test.json' USING
    JsonLoader('revenue:int,products:{(name:chararray,price:int)}');
```