# Parse Complex JSON String in Pig

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I want to parse a string of complex JSON in Pig. Specifically, I want Pig to understand my JSON array as a bag instead of as a single chararray. When using JsonLoader, I can do this easily by specifying the schema, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094768/parsing-complex-json-with-pig). Is there any way to either have Pig figure out my schema for me, or to specify it when Pig is parsing a string? I've been using [JsonStringToMap](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/piggybank/JsonStringToMap.java), but can't find a way to specify Schema, or to have it properly understand my JSON array is an array and not a single chararray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wound up using [JsonTupleMap()](https://github.com/mozilla-metrics/akela/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mozilla/pig/eval/json/JsonTupleMap.java) in [Mozilla's Akela library for pig](https://github.com/mozilla-metrics/akela). It accomplishes exactly what I want by parsing all of my JSON even when it's complex, and doing this even when I don't provide a schema. If you run into the same problem as me, use that.

Example usage:

```
REGISTER '/path/to/akela-0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar';
DEFINE JsonTupleMap com.mozilla.pig.eval.json.JsonTupleMap();
loaded = LOAD '$INPUT' AS (json_string:chararray, ...);
jsonified = FOREACH loaded GENERATE JsonTupleMap(json_string) AS json:map[], ...;
some_generate = FOREACH jsonified GENERATE json#'key'#'sub_key';
```

Comment: do you know where I can find the compiled jar file?

Comment: @FabrizioRegini there are instructions in the link above for compiling the jar using Maven. It's very easy. You'll need to compile for your particular system.

Comment: I was having problems compiling elephant-bird and someone pointed me to the jar file download. This is why I'm asking.

Comment: There are likely native flags in the source code for platform-based optimization. I'd strongly recommend compiling on the same environment as what you'll be using in production to take advantage of these.