# Pig parsing json inside of Avro

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, avro

I have avro file which has two fields (let say event_type and event_content). So I can load this avro file by using avro load function:

```
avro = LOAD '$home/part-00000.avro'
USING AvroStorage ();
```

Second field (event_content) is nested json file. Is there any way how to parse json from this second field after i load avro file? I do not want to write custom UDF.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128068/parse-complex-json-string-in-pig/16642645#16642645

Comment: What does the event_content actually hold? Can you post the schema for your Avro file?

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. It was pain to build it, but it works great!